# Facebook app got blocked

Tags: facebook, blocked

![enter image description here][1]

I got my facebook app blocked and i dont know what is the reason ...

This is what i seen :

"  'app name' has been restricted
Your app has been restricted by Facebook. 
Uploading and tagging photos disabled"

It created 12,000 added and 300 removed that app so far..It was very famous and was getting viral with in 1 day..But suddenly facebook blocked it..

1   Photo Reports?
0   Self-reported Photo Spam?
12  Friend-reported Photo Spam?
0   Photo Tag Spam?

Please tell me why they blocked me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 0):

This is because most of the user has removed the tags from the your uploaded photos.
that why facebook has banned the uploading and tagging of photos.
but as if you are saying

> "It created 12,000 added and 300 removed that app so far"..

but still if you are thinking its wrong then you can submit your request to facebook to remove the ban on uploading and tagging of photos.

Comment: But i didn't tagged anyone..My app just uploads the picture to there wall with a small message.That's all.. :(